# Android 13 NotificationCompat setSound STREAM_ALARM not using Alarm volume

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am creating an app which when needed would send a notification with sound. It is important that the notification would be heard even on silent or "do not disturb" so I want to ride the phone's Alarm volume.
I'm using and modifying code from an open source package [react-native-alarm-notification](https://github.com/emekalites/react-native-alarm-notification)

Here's some of my code-

```js
// some code for creating the alarm object and getting the settings

// creating the builder
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelID)
  .setSmallIcon(smallIconResId)
  .setContentTitle(title)
  .setContentText(message)
  .setTicker(alarm.getTicker())
  .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
  .setAutoCancel(alarm.isAutoCancel())
  .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
  .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
  .setSound(null)
  .setDeleteIntent(createOnDismissedIntent(context, alarm.getId()));

if (alarm.isPlaySound()) {
  // THE IMPORTANT BIT
  mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE),
    AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
}

...//more settings


// set tag and push notification
Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

String tag = alarm.getTag();
if (tag != null && !tag.equals("")) {
  mNotificationManager.notify(tag, notificationID, notification);
} else {
  Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Notification done");
  mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);
}
```

The problem is that the notification still defaults to Android 13's notification sound setting, and not using the Alarm volume setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know if what I tried to do is possible but I found a different solution.

Basically I created a separate audio interface using `MediaPlayer`, that whenever a notification is sent, it also starts an alarm, and when the notification is dismissed, it stops the alarm.